# Chrome Extension Cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try get cookie from page with extension but when i write `console.log(chrome)` return object but cookies key not exist 
This is my manifest json

```
{
  "name": "Call Center",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Extension For Call Center",
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://*.youtube.com/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js","hello.js"]
}
```

Comment: `cookies` is a value, not the key. The key for `cookies` is `permissions`.

Comment: chrome.cookies API is not available in a content script. Use an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter You call chrome.cookies look like this true?